# How to make a custom object iterable?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, iterable

I have a `list` of custom-class objects (sample is below).

Using: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(myBigList))` I wanted to "merge" all of the `stations` sublists into one big list. So I thought I need to make my custom class an iterable.

Here is a sample of my custom class.

```
class direction(object) :
    def __init__(self, id) :
        self.id = id              
        self.__stations = list()

    def __iter__(self):
        self.__i = 0                #  iterable current item 
        return iter(self.__stations)

    def __next__(self):
        if self.__i<len(self.__stations)-1:
            self.__i += 1         
            return self.__stations[self.__i]
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

I implemented `__iter__` and `__next__` but it doesn't seems to work. They're not even called.

Any idea what could I've done wrong?

Note: Using Python 3.3

Comment: Are you subclassing `list`?

Comment: Nope, a List is just a member of my class.

Comment: Is that the actual indentation? `__iter__` and `__next__` are *outside* your class definition.

Comment: After fixing the indentation it works for me: `list(chain.from_iterable([direction(10), direction(20)]))`, returns `[]`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry bad copy/paste. My indent was good.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- But `direction.__next__` won't be called.  `direction_instance.__stations.__next__` will be.

Comment: @mgilson Oops!, you're right, I totally missed that part.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`__iter__` is what gets called when you try to iterate over a class instance:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return (x for x in range(4))
...
>>> list(Foo())
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

`__next__` is what gets called on the object which is returned from `__iter__` (on python2.x, it's `next`, not `__next__` -- I generally alias them both so that the code will work with either...):

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.idx = 0
        self.data = range(4)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        self.idx += 1
        try:
            return self.data[self.idx-1]
        except IndexError:
            self.idx = 0
            raise StopIteration  # Done iterating.
    next = __next__  # python2.x compatibility.
```

In the comments, it was asked how you would construct and object that could be iterated multiple times.  In this case, I'd recommend taking the same approach that Python takes and split the iterator from the data container:

```
class BarIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, data_sequence):
        self.idx = 0
        self.data = data_sequence
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        self.idx += 1
        try:
            return self.data[self.idx-1]
        except IndexError:
            self.idx = 0
            raise StopIteration  # Done iterating.


class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, data_sequence):
        self.data_sequence = data_sequence
    def __iter__(self):
        return BarIterator(self.data_sequence)
```

Comment: Well I'm really confused, because I was my code around that was wrong. But your answer did make it a bit clearer to me how iterables work !

Comment: Why not just return the iterator of `self.data`? While fine for OP's purposes, this is not thread safe. You can call `next()` on the iterator before returning it if you want to skip the first element.

Comment: @MadPhysicist -- That's a fair point.  It's been 2 years since I answered this, but I _think_ that the reason that I did it this way was to demonstrate to OP how to use the iterator protocol with `__iter__` and `__next__`.

Comment: @mgilson. Makes sense. Valuable answer either way.

Comment: What should I do to allow multiple loops over this object? Should I reset self.idx to 0 on the call to __iter()__?

Comment: In that case, I'd take a page out of what the stdlib does for buildin containers -- e.g. `list._iter__` returns a `listiterator` instance.  The `listiterator` is still only once iterable.  It's really just an index and a pointer back to the original data.  In this way, a caller can call `iter(some_list)` as many times as they want and get independent iterators each time.

Comment: > What should I do to allow multiple loops over this object? Should I reset self.idx to 0 on the call to iter()

From [Iterator Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types):

> Once an iterator’s __next__() method raises StopIteration, it must continue to do so on subsequent calls. Implementations that do not obey this property are deemed broken.

Comment: @MikeKaganski -- updated the answer to hopefully address your question.

Comment: I likely was unclear. I didn't ask a question, I rather answered a question by @zzz777 above (quoting their question, and then quoting an excerpt from the documentation, to show that the repeated iteration using the same iterator is against the standard).

Answer (score 8):

simply implementing `__iter__` should be enough.

```
class direction(object) :
    def __init__(self, id) :
        self.id = id              
        self.__stations = list()

    def __iter__(self):
        #return iter(self.__stations[1:]) #uncomment this if you wanted to skip the first element.
        return iter(self.__stations)


a = direction(1)
a._direction__stations= range(5)

b = direction(1)
b._direction__stations = range(10)

import itertools
print list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([a,b]))
print list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([range(5),range(10)]))
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) for why it's `_direction__stations`

> Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores,
>   at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with
>   *classname*_spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped.

Comment: You need to use `iter(self.__stations[1:])`, as per OP's code they are skipping the first item.

Comment: I'll at it as an option with uncommenting code. since he did not explicitly say that was what he wanted. I'll assume that more natural implementation of giving all elements. And that his original implementation of `next`had a little bug in it.

Comment: Or, `x = iter(self.__stations); next(x); return x` if you don't want to make an unnecessary copy ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass `list` as well:

```
class Direction(list):
    def __init__(self, seq=[], id_=None):
        list.__init__(self,seq)
        self.id = id_ if id_ else id(self)

    def __iter__(self):
        it=list.__iter__(self) 
        next(it)                       # skip the first...
        return it  

d=Direction(range(10))
print(d)       # all the data, no iteration
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

print (', '.join(str(e) for e in d))     # 'for e in d' is an iterator
# 1, 2, 3, 4
```

ie, skips the first.

Works for nested lists as well:

```
>>> d1=Direction([range(5), range(10,15), range(20,25)])
>>> d1
[range(0, 5), range(10, 15), range(20, 25)]
print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(d1)))
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```