# Object not iterable in python when created made class iterable for objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I am making a program where I need to iterate through every option in a class to perform actions to each object, to do that I made an 'IterRegistry' Class to turn the metaclass of my objects to iterable but for some reason, it still isn't working.

```
class IterRegistry(type):
    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(cls._registry)


class TreeLine(object):
    __metaclass__ = IterRegistry
    _registry = []

    def __init__(self, earnings, buy_price):
        self._registry.append(self)
        self.earnings = earnings
        self.buy_prince = buy_price


TreeLine(0, 0)
TreeLine(0, 7)

for i in TreeLine:
    print(i)
```

I just get the error message:   File "/Users/PycharmProjects/AISTUFF/venv/OSI@.py", line 23, in 
    for i in TreeLine:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Comment: You need to make your class iterable, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665485/how-to-make-a-custom-object-iterable

Comment: You want to make `IterRegistry.__iter__` a `@classmethod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a class metaclass like this:

```
class TreeLine(object):
    __metaclass__ = IterRegistry
```

does not work in Python 3.  Instead, the metaclass is declared like this:

```
class TreeLine(metaclass=IterRegistry):
    ...
```

The syntax is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses).  The change was proposed in [PEP3115](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115).

Note that the `__metaclass__` form is not invalid syntax, it just doesn't behave as in Python 2.

```
>>> class M(type):pass
... 
>>> class C:
...     __metaclass__ = M
... 
>>> type(C)
<class 'type'>
>>> class D(metaclass=M):pass
... 
>>> type(D)
<class '__main__.M'>
>>>
```