# How to reset pointer after break in for loop

Tags: python, class, iterable

I have a class called ObjectSet that I want to be iterable. It resets my "pointer" after a for loop but not if I break the loop.

My class ObjectSet has the methods defined in the attached code. I loop through an object set and when I find a particular object, i break the loop, but I don't know how to reset the pointer in this case in a good way.

```
class ObjectSet:

   def __init__(self,objects = None):
      if not objects: self.objects = []
      else: self.objects = objects
      self.pointer = 0
   def __iter__(self):
      return self
   def __len__(self):
      return len(self.objects)
   def __next__(self):
      cur_pointer = self.pointer
      if cur_pointer >= len(self):
         self.pointer = 0
         raise StopIteration
      self.pointer += 1
      return self.objects[cur_pointer]


objs = ObjectSet([1,2,3])
for obj in objs:
   if obj == 2:
      break
for obj in objs:
   print(obj)
```

The code only prints 3, but I want it to print 1,2, and 3, as it does with a list.

Comment: the answer to the proposed duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665485/how-to-make-a-custom-object-iterable is exactly the code as presented in this question...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate, I missed that one.

Comment: i did not mean to tell you that there is a duplicate; quite the opposite. someone had closed your question with the link above as duplicate. i reopened it because the **answer** there is your **question** (and will not work in your case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could implement the [iterator pattern](https://python-patterns.guide/gang-of-four/iterator/).

but given that your basic data structure supports iteration already you could just do this:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.objects)
```

(and remove the `__next__` method and `self.pointer` from your class).

the problem with your design is that there is only one `self.pointer` per instance of your class `ObjectSet`. but as you noticed only the iterator you return should remember the next position. that is what the iterator pattern would do for you.