# How do I "run" a function that is in a queue?

Tags: python, queue, pyautogui

Basically I created a queue in Python with some functions (that the user put in the order he wants) and now I want to execute this functions in order, but I really didn't find what which order do that.
The queue:

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = []
        
    def enqueue(self, data):
        self.elements.append(data)
        return data
    
    def dequeue(self):
        return self.elements.pop(0)
    
    def rear(self): 
        return self.elements[-1]

    def front(self):
        return self.elements[0]

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self.elements) == 0
```

The functions:

```
if (escolha=='2'):
        print("Type your hotkey. Ex: alt+tab+ [3 keys maximum]")
        my_var = input("")
        my_var = my_var.split('+')
        def hotchave():
            pyautogui.hotkey(str(my_var[0]),str(my_var[1]),str(my_var[2]))
        queue.enqueue(hotchave)
        
if (escolha=='3'):
        write=input('What will be written?: ')
        def escrever():
            pyautogui.write(write)
        queue.enqueue(escrever)
```

I already tried things like return, front but didn't seem to work.

Comment: `queue.dequeue()()` — also note that Python has a `Queue` class you could use instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yes, i know, but for this I want to see how it works. Is there some form to do this but without taking the function out of the queue? I want to repeat the queue for a number of times.

Comment: Your class only provides methods to look at the first or last element without removing them — so you would need to add something to it in order to do what you want. Alternatively you could just access `queue.elements` the way you would any other list.

Comment: Thanks, I will look to do that.

Comment: See [How to make a custom object iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665485/how-to-make-a-custom-object-iterable) for one possibly.

Comment: Yeah I see, just one more question. What does de second () means in queue.dequeue()()?

Comment: It calls the function returned from the call to `dequeue`.

Answer (score 0):

There's several different ways to do what you want, some of which require to modify your class. Since you say you would like to retrieve and run multiple functions from the queue, I would suggest making it possible to iterate its current contents, which can be done simply by adding an `__iter__()` method to the class.

The following shows how to do that, along with how to make use of it.

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = []

    def enqueue(self, data):
        self.elements.append(data)
        return data

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.elements.pop(0)

    def rear(self):
        return self.elements[-1]

    def front(self):
        return self.elements[0]

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self.elements) == 0

    def __iter__(self):
        '''Iterate current contents.'''
        return (elem for elem in self.elements)
```

Sample usage:

```
queue = Queue()

my_var = 'alt+shift+k'
my_var = my_var.split('+')
def hotchave():
    print('vars:', str(my_var[0]), str(my_var[1]), str(my_var[2]))
queue.enqueue(hotchave)

write = 'This will be written'
def escrever():
    print(write)
queue.enqueue(escrever)

# Execute commands in Queue.
for command in queue:
    command()
print('-fini-')
```

Output:

```
vars: alt shift k
This will be written
-fini-
```